# Check if UI(Managed)Document is already in iCloud via URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier+Path instead of NSMetadataQuery?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, icloud, uimanageddocument

I have a quite simple shoebox-style iOS app with **1** single **Core Data** database (as a **UIManagedDocument**) and thought about trying to add **iCloud** support.

---

I of course have to **check if** there is already an **existing** database **in the cloud** **before creating a new UIManagedDocument at startup**, saving/opening it, etc.

As i **already know the filename** and that there's either 1 document or no document at all, I didn't really get if I had to

1. start a **NSMetaDataQuery** with a predicate for the **exact filename**
   and then **get** the **fileURL from the result** (and download it
   explicitly?) and open it if there is one, or
2. just use `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:self.iCloudDBURL]`
   with `iCloudDBURL` created from **URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier** + appending ? Is this URL only a local one and doesn't check the "real" cloud automatically?

---

I know the use of UIManagedDocument might not be the "right" way for this kind of app, but I thought it'd easier and I could try..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `NSMetadataQuery` approach.

When using iOS on iCloud, documents don't download automatically-- they only download when you ask for them. Using `NSFileManager` as you suggest would only tell you if the file existed on the local device. But, the file might exist up in the cloud, not downloaded locally yet. If you use `NSMetadataQuery` you can find out if the document exists *anywhere*, even if it's in the cloud and not actually downloaded yet. You can find out about the document if it was created on a different device. This also covers the case where the user deletes and reinstalls the app, but doesn't delete cloud data-- you find out if it exists even though it's not downloaded.

Since you're using `UIManagedDocument` you shouldn't need to make a specific download call-- it will handle that for you when you open it.